# Playing Sounds and removing instances once they have played -- Android

Tags: android, sound

I am playing sounds in my application I have the following code

```
sounds = new HashMap<String, MediaPlayer>();
```

Then when guys are created on screen they are given a sound.

```
sounds.put("sounds"+Integer.toString(ncount), MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hit));
```

I want to remove the MediaPlayer from the hashmap like I do the enemies when they die

```
sounds.get("sounds"+Integer.toString(ncount)).setOnCompletionListener( new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        sounds.remove("sounds"+Integer.toString(ncount));
    }


});
```

This errors out... how would I reference the sounds hashmap to remove the associated MediaPlayer when sound is complete?

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Additionally, some of your questions are purely programming questions and not particularly about game development. Since the number of Android developers on this site is still low, you might want to try asking on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is `ncount` a static variable? If that's the case it is very likely that `ncount` has changed when `onCompletion` gets called (because `ncount` was modified during playing of the sound). You should probably use another method to build that identifier...